# AuthorizationHandler Manager For Identity

Tags: asp.net, identity

public class CanEditOnlyOtherAdminRolesAndClaimsHandler : AuthorizationHandler
    {
        private readonly UserManager _userManager;
        public CanEditOnlyOtherAdminRolesAndClaimsHandler(UserManager userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

```
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ManageAdminRolesAndClaimsRequirement requirement)
    {
        var authFilterContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
        if (authFilterContext == null)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var loggedInAdminId = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        ApplicationUser adminIdBeingEdited = authFilterContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["userId"];




        if (context.User.IsInRole("Admin") && context.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "Edit Role" && claim.Value == "true") &&
            (adminIdBeingEdited.ToLower() != loggedInAdminId?.ToLower()))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

}

344/5000
Hi
These codes belong to my project.
I would like to write a code that if a user tries to edit Super Admin will not be able to do so.
That is, I originally wanted to get the role of the user who is editing, if the user being edited in Super Admin would not allow the user to edit.
In essence, I want to make the admin user not have access to the role of super admin.